# How to represent a Reverse Proxy in a diagram?

Tags: http

I'm putting together a diagram to represent the proposed flow of HTTP traffic after we make some architectural changes. One of the proposals includes adding a reverse proxy.

Is there a recognizable way to represent traffic routing through a reverse proxy or should I just use a plain arrow and tack on a "reverse proxy" label?

Additionally I may need to show 303 redirects in the same diagram. Is there a recognizable way to represent redirects?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the same representation as a standard proxy server.  Functionally, there isn't *really* a difference between a proxy that's at a client's office location for instance, and a reverse proxy in your network.  The difference of course is that you have more control over what the proxy does to the requests from the client since it's yours, allowing you to do "cooler" stuff like injecting javascript, headers, or cookies.

At the end of the day, the proxy is the endpoint for the TCP session, injects an X-Forwarded-For header (among other stuff) and caches some stuff.

Stackoverflow has a question on it with a pretty good answer to provide details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server